# Android power save mode listener?

Tags: android

How can an Android listener be created to perform a task just before entering power save mode? Also: what are some of the low power options that can be controlled by this task?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer above(for API 21 and above) is not exactly right. You should register a receiver in your activity or service like this:

```
BroadcastReceiver powerSaverChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        checkPowerSaverMode();
    }
 };

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.os.action.POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED");
registerReceiver(powerSaverChangeReceiver, filter);
```

The reason for this is that receivers in manifest are not triggered by this broadcast.

> ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED
>
> Intent that is broadcast when the state of isPowerSaveMode() changes. This broadcast is only sent to registered receivers.

I have tested this and it works.

Comment: Is there a way to simply check if device is in power save mode?

Comment: @jmrodrigg you can just use

```PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
boolean powerSave == m.isPowerSaveMode();
```

Comment: @nattster Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Since Lollipop (API 21) there is [PowerManager#ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED) broadcast intent.

So you need just to receive it:

---

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".observers.PowerSaveModeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.os.action.POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED"/> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

---

PowerSaveModeReceiver.java:

```
public class PowerSaveModeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEV_LOGS)
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), String.format("onReceive(context = [%s], intent = [%s])", context, intent));

        final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (pm.isPowerSaveMode()) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do some else
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work for you? It is written in the docs "This broadcast is only sent to registered receivers." ...

Answer (score 1):

> How can an Android listener be created to perform a task just before entering power save mode?

There is no broadcast `Intent` for this. The closest is `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`. The device will likely fall asleep in the near future after you receive this broadcast. And, you can only listen for this broadcast using a `BroadcastReceiver` registered via `registerReceiver()` in an activity or service or other `Context`.

> Also: what are some of the low power options that can be controlled by this task?

I have no idea what this means, sorry.

Comment: Screen off is one part of power save that can be disabled in Settings > Applications > Development. Can other power save functions such as closing the microSD card interface be controlled by an application?

Comment: @JackN: I am unclear what you think "closing the microSD card interface" is. Please see `android.provider.Settings.System` for the sorts of things you can control. Beyond that list, there is nothing power-related I can think of along the lines you seem to be interested in.