# Determine when WIFI goes in Power save mode during multicast

Tags: android, multicast

I am researching how Android behaves when receiving data over wifi via Multicast. In relation to this I need to determine, when the phones wifi goes to power save mode during multicast and the time spend in power save mode.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to determine this?

Comment: Please try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139149/android-power-save-mode-listener

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065635/checking-for-power-saver-mode-programically

Comment: @Adnanul but that is not what I am looking for. Its is power save for wifi and not battery I am interested in